# 1 pixel table border in JTextPane using HTML

Tags: java, html, swing, jtextpane

I'm using a JTextPane to display some HTML that contains a table with a border. I want it to have a simple 1 pixel border.

I tried using `style="border: 1px solid; border-collapse:collapse"`. This works in a web browser, but not in JTextPane.

Is there any way to have a simple 1 pixel table border using HTML in a JTextPane?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a complete example:

```
package test

import java.awt.SystemColor;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HtmlDemo extends JPanel {

    public HtmlDemo() {
        setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

        String rgb = Integer.toHexString(SystemColor.window.getRGB());
        String backgroundColor = rgb.substring(2, rgb.length());

        String html = "<html>\n"
            + "<head>\n"
            + "<style type=\"text/css\">\n"
            + "table {\n" + "width: 100%\n" + "}\n"
            + "td, th {\n" + "background-color: #" + backgroundColor + "\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "</style>\n"
            + "</head>\n"
            + "<body>\n"
            + "HTML table test:\n"
            + "<div style=\"background-color: black\">\n"
            + "<table border=\"0\" cellpadding=\"2\" cellspacing=\"1\">\n"
            + "<tr>\n" + "<td>\n" + "cell1\n" + "</td>\n" + "<td>\n" + "cell2\n" + "</td>\n" + "</tr>\n"
            + "<tr>\n" + "<td>\n" + "cell3\n" + "</td>\n" + "<td>\n" + "cell4\n" + "</td>\n" + "</tr>\n"
            + "</div>\n"
            + "</body>\n"
            + "</html>";

        JLabel label = new JLabel(html);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        add(label);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("HtmlDemo");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new HtmlDemo());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Small detail: You forgot to close the `<table>` tag: `</table>`. But thanx for this answer, really useful ;-)

Answer (score 8):

Use a combination of

```
public static final String TD = "<td style='background-color: white'></td>";
public static final String TABLE_PROP = "style='border: 1px black solid; background-color: black' width='100%' cellspacing='1' cellpadding='2'";


String html = "<table " + TABLE_PROP + ">" + "<tr>" + TD + TD + "</tr><tr>" + TD + TD + "</tr></table>";
try
{
            htmlEditorKit.insertHTML(htmlDocument, caretPosition, html, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Comment: Great workaround! To reduce repeating code I have create following styles: ```table { border: 1px black solid; background-color: black;}``` and ```td, th { background-color: white; }```

Answer (score 1):

[`javax.swing.text.html`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/package-summary.html) is based on [`HTML 3.2`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32.html), but you can use the *border* attribute of the `<table>` tag.

Comment: Setting border=1 doesn't create a 1 pixel border, because each cell has it's own border.

Comment: @Chris B: You may have to adjust `cellspacing` and `cellpadding`, too.

Answer (score 0):

trashgod is right - Java's HTML support is limited - so why not use an HTML workaround?  Just put your table (with no borders) inside another table with one cell that has a border.

```
<table id='outerTable' border='1'><tr><td>
   <table id='innerTable'>
      // Content here
   </table>
</td></tr></table>
```

It's not the cleanest of methods, but it does get around HTML 3.2 limitations.'

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to create a border to a table on preferable colour in HTML 3.2:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="1" bgcolor="#000000">
        <tr><td>
            <table width="100%"  bgcolor="#F6F6F6">
              <tr><td>   
                Test                 
              </td></tr>              
            </table>
        </td></tr></table>
```